# Simple Routing with Bolt cms and Silex

Tags: php, silex, bolt-cms

I am working on creating an extension for Bolt Cms.

In essence I am wanting to read the URL and reroute based on whatever the outcome is.

My Output is

**NO You Are Here**

Any help is GREATLY appreciated

```
namespace Bolt\Extension\local\johnm\test;

use Bolt\BaseExtension;


class Extension extends BaseExtension
{
public function initialize()
{


    $config = $this->app['config']->get('/editcontent/{contenttypeslug}/{id}', function () {

        echo "QWERTY";
        exit;
    });

    $config = $this->app['controllers_factory']->get('/overview/{contenttypeslug}', function () {

        echo "QWERTY";
        exit;
    });

    $config = $this->app['controllers_factory']->match('/content/{action}/{contenttypeslug}/{id}', function () {

        echo "QWERTY";
        exit;
    });


    echo "No You Are HERE";
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you aware that your code does nothing more that declare 3 routes and then *always* execute the last echo and the exit? So if you call exit your PHP script will always end

Comment: Hi There thanks for the feedback, I am afraid I do not understand. Am I not with the ->match() method waiting for a URL to match the first string parameter and then echo out whatever is in its function? eg QWERTY

Comment: Yes, but after declaring the 3 routes you **always** call the ```echo "No you are here";``` and the ```exit``` instructions, and when php reaches the exit function it stops its processing so you'll only see "No you are here" no nothing else whichever URL you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above I am registering the routes you see, the problem is that the routes are already declared so others will take president, What I did was create a completely different root and register that.

```
public function initialize()
        {
        $this->app->get('bolt/revision/{contentType}/{id}',array($this,'getRevision'));

}
```

When a URL matches this, a function entitled getRevision() is called which is in THIS class